# Returning RecordCount from Get-WinEvent in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a PowerShell script that will count the number of records from the
requested log with a specific id that have occurred in the last `$interval`
seconds.  In the current version of the script, I am printing the `$log` of
events returned, as well as the `RecordCount`.  However, the `RecordCount` is
not printing.

The current version of my script is:

```
$log_name = 'Application'
$event_id = 1003
$interval = (get-date).AddSeconds(-7200)  # Last 2 hours.
$count = 0

$log = Get-WinEvent -EA silentlycontinue `
                    -FilterHashTable @{ LogName=$log_name;
                                        StartTime=$interval;
                                        id=$event_id }

$log
$log.RecordCount
```

The output is:

```
PS C:\temp> .\log_monitor

TimeCreated                   ProviderName                                             Id Message
-----------                   ------------                                             -- -------
01/25/2016 12:34:40 PM        Office Software Protection...                          1003 The Software Protection se...
01/25/2016 12:34:40 PM        Office Software Protection...                          1003 The Software Protection se...
01/25/2016 12:34:39 PM        Office Software Protection...                          1003 The Software Protection se...
01/25/2016 12:34:39 PM        Office Software Protection...                          1003 The Software Protection se...
01/25/2016 12:14:22 PM        Office Software Protection...                          1003 The Software Protection se...
01/25/2016 12:14:22 PM        Office Software Protection...                          1003 The Software Protection se...
01/25/2016 12:14:22 PM        Office Software Protection...                          1003 The Software Protection se...
01/25/2016 12:14:22 PM        Office Software Protection...                          1003 The Software Protection se...
01/25/2016 12:05:41 PM        Office Software Protection...                          1003 The Software Protection se...
01/25/2016 12:05:41 PM        Office Software Protection...                          1003 The Software Protection se...
01/25/2016 12:05:41 PM        Office Software Protection...                          1003 The Software Protection se...
01/25/2016 12:05:41 PM        Office Software Protection...                          1003 The Software Protection se...


PS C:\temp>
```

Note that the `RecordCount` is not printing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead just use the `Count` property like

```
$log.Count
```

Comment: That worked.  Thanks.  An additional question though.  If `Get-Event .... | Where { $_.RecordCount }` works correctly, then why wouldn't `$log.RecordCount`?  Just trying to understand, as I don't script in PowerShell that often.

Comment: @DougR. that probably because of the different object type it returns based on the input. Do a `get-help Get-WinEvent -full` and see the `OutPut` section. You use `RecordCount` property only when you use `ListLog` input and not in any other scenario. In your case even `{$_.RecordCount}` won't return anything.